# gitlab port forward tom foolery

Tags: linux, networking, port, port-forwarding, gitlab

We have a public-facing web server (CentOS 6 w/ Apache) that will need to forward requests, both from public and a private interface, to a separate host that's running Gitlab.  For security purposes, we were unable to stand up a new host that had a public.  We've chosen a non-standard SSH port to be used as the forwarding port to send on to the Gitlab machine.  The question is, how best should we implement this so that users doing a git push/pull etc. For reference, here's a diagram showing what we're after:

[image: Network Diagram]

We're trying to make this as user-friendly as possible so we were thinking perhaps some kind of port trigger mechanism for git requests to automatically forward through the `PublicWebServer` using port 2500 to the gitlab internal machine listening on the default 22.  Internal users would use the same basic process.  The `PublicWebServer` is dual-homed.

If not port trigger, does this concept at least seem sound?  Could this be accomplished using `iptables`?